# Where can I download fluke?

Tags: audio, itunes, download, flac

I am a Mac user, playing media using iTunes. I recently heard about using fluke to import FLAC files into iTunes, but it seems that the fluke project isn't around any more. All links pointing to it take me to a "not found" page. Can someone either point me to a place where I can still download it, or tell me about another tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go, version 0.2.5b.

[Fluke for Mac](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/28768/fluke/) on MacUpdate.com

> Fluke is a small Mac OS X utility that lets you listen to your FLAC files right within iTunes without needing to convert anything. Simply feed your FLACs into it and watch the magic happen!

Here's another link to the [Google Code download site](http://code.google.com/p/flukeformac/downloads/list).